# Add action on delete comments?

Tags: comments, database

I add some input fields to the comment form, and than this new data is stored on commentmeta table. 
When a comment is deleted, the data on commentmeta is still there.

How can I delete these data when a comment is deleted? (I need an action similar to the delete_post but for comments...does it exists?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Look at the function `wp_delete_comment()`. It fires an action before the comment is deleted:

```
/**
 * Fires immediately before a comment is deleted from the database.
 *
 * @since 1.2.0
 *
 * @param int $comment_id The comment ID.
 */
do_action( 'delete_comment', $comment_id );
```

… and one after deletion:

```
/**
 * Fires immediately after a comment is deleted from the database.
 *
 * @since 2.9.0
 *
 * @param int $comment_id The comment ID.
 */
do_action( 'deleted_comment', $comment_id );
```

So you can bind your callback to that:

```
add_action( 'deleted_comment', function( $comment_id ) {
    delete_comment_meta( $comment_id, 'your_meta_key' );
} );
```